# Prefer extension methods for encapsulation and reusability?

Tags: c#, c++, extension-methods, encapsulation

**edit4:** *wikified, since this seems to have morphed more into a discussion than a specific question.*

In C++ programming, it's generally considered good practice to "prefer non-member non-friend functions" instead of instance methods. This has been recommended by Scott Meyers in [this classic Dr. Dobbs article](http://www.drdobbs.com/184401197), and repeated by Herb Sutter and Andrei Alexandrescu in [C++ Coding Standards](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c++cs.htm) (item 44); the general argument being that if a function can do its job solely by relying on the public interface exposed by the class, it actually *increases* encapsulation to have it be external. While this confuses the "packaging" of the class to some extent, the benefits are generally considered worth it.

Now, ever since I've started programming in C#, I've had a feeling that **here** is the ultimate expression of the *concept* that they're trying to achieve with "non-member, non-friend functions that are part of a class interface". C# adds two crucial components to the mix - the first being [interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx), and the second [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx):

- Interfaces allow a class to formally specify their public contract, the methods and properties that they're exposing to the world.
- Any other class can choose to implement the same interface and fulfill that same contract.
- Extension methods can be defined *on* an interface, providing any functionality that can be implemented via the interface to all implementers *automatically*.
- And best of all, because of the "instance syntax" sugar and IDE support, they can be called *the same way* as any other instance method, eliminating the cognitive overhead!

So you get the encapsulation benefits of "non-member, non-friend" functions with the convenience of members. Seems like the best of both worlds to me; the .NET library itself providing a shining example in LINQ. However, everywhere I look I see people warning against extension method overuse; even the MSDN page itself states:

> In general, we recommend that you implement extension methods sparingly and only when you have to.

(**edit:** Even in the current .NET library, I can see places where it would've been useful to have extensions instead of instance methods - for example, all of the utility functions of `List<T>` (`Sort`, `BinarySearch`, `FindIndex`, etc.) would be incredibly useful if they were lifted up to `IList<T>` - getting free bonus functionality like that adds a lot more benefit to implementing the interface.)

So what's the verdict? Are extension methods the acme of encapsulation and code reuse, or am I just deluding myself?

(**edit2:** In response to Tomas - while C# did start out with Java's (overly, imo) OO mentality, it seems to be embracing more multi-paradigm programming with every new release; the main thrust of this question is whether using extension methods to drive a style change (towards more generic / functional C#) is useful or worthwhile..)

#### edit3: overridable extension methods

The only real problem identified so far with this approach, is that you can't specialize extension methods if you need to. I've been thinking about the issue, and I think I've come up with a solution.
Suppose I have an interface `MyInterface`, which I want to extend -

I define my extension methods in a `MyExtension` static class, and pair it with another interface, call it `MyExtensionOverrider`. `MyExtension` methods are defined according to this pattern:

```
public static int MyMethod(this MyInterface obj, int arg, bool attemptCast=true)
{
    if (attemptCast && obj is MyExtensionOverrider)
    {
        return ((MyExtensionOverrider)obj).MyMethod(arg);
    }
    // regular implementation here
}
```

The override interface mirrors all of the methods defined in `MyExtension`, except without the `this` or `attemptCast` parameters:

```
public interface MyExtensionOverrider
{
    int MyMethod(int arg);
    string MyOtherMethod();
}
```

Now, any class can implement the interface and get the default extension functionality:

```
public class MyClass : MyInterface { ... }
```

Anyone that wants to override it with specific implementations can additionally implement the override interface:

```
public class MySpecializedClass : MyInterface, MyExtensionOverrider
{
    public int MyMethod(int arg) 
    { 
        //specialized implementation for one method
    }
    public string MyOtherMethod() 
    {   // fallback to default for others
        MyExtension.MyOtherMethod(this, attemptCast: false); 
    }
}
```

And there we go: extension methods provided on an interface, with the option of complete extensibility if needed. Fully general too, the interface itself doesn't need to know about the extension / override, and multiple extension / override pairs can be implemented without interfering with each other.

I can see three problems with this approach -

1. It's a little bit fragile - the extension methods and override interface have to be kept synchronized manually.
2. It's a little bit ugly - implementing the override interface involves boilerplate for every function you *don't* want to specialize.
3. It's a little bit slow - there's an extra `bool` comparison and cast attempt added to the mainline of every method.

Still, all those notwithstanding, I think this is the best we can get until there's language support for interface functions. Thoughts?

Comment: When you say C# adds interfaces, it makes me think C++ doesn't have them.  C++ has them (mostly) via pure virtual functions.

Comment: If an extension method is so important that he needs to be present in all implementors of a base class, why isn't it in the base class in the first place ?

Comment: @SB: Abstract base classes aren't _quite_ the same thing. 
@ereOn: Because it's better for encapsulation to not allow access to class internals unless you absolutely have to. Read the first article I linked in the question.

Comment: @ereOn, how would you get LINQ to work without rewriting the entire .Net Framework and CLR if the extension methods were methods on a base class?

Comment: An interesting article from Joe Duffy showing some of the pros and cons of this kind of approach: http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2010/02/10/ExtensionMethodsAsDefaultInterfaceMethodImplementations.aspx

Comment: @Matthew: I don't know LINQ. But i'm not sure to get your point: do you say LINQ do things that **can only** be done using extensions methods ? That seems weird.

Comment: @LukeH - that's a nice article, thanks!

Comment: @ereOn, you could do LINQ without extension methods... but it would be very nasty. You would either need every enumerable type object to inherit from a common base class. Or you could have to have fun things in your code like... `Enumerable.Where(yourListObject, record=>record.Value==matchedValue)` instead of `yourListObject.Where(record=>record.Value==matchedValue)` ... I vote for the second (with interfaces and extension methods.)

Comment: @Matthew: Why couldn't `Where` be a base class method as well in the first case ?! To me, extensions methods are like patches: they do the work, but when you applied the fifth patch on your class, you somehow wish you would have designed it better in the first place.

Comment: @ereOn, because you would need to rewrite the entire .Net framework and all business apps written on top of it.  As well as you would have duplicate code and probably need to rewrite the CLR so it supported multiple inheritance.  Extension methods could be used like patches.  And that would probably be a very broken approach.  But they can also be used to extend existing classes in a clean way without rewriting the world. (Such as adding searching, paging, and composition to all IEnumerable<> types in existence… ie. LINQ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I generally like extension methods, particularly on interfaces, but I have two issues with them:

First, if an implementation has a more efficient way of achieving the extension method's purpose, there's no general way of expressing that. For example, `Enumerable.Count()` *explicitly* knows about `ICollection`/`ICollection<T>` and special-cases it. An alternative for this would be if interfaces could actually contain implementations directly, referencing only other interface methods and *not* declaring fields. The methods could then be overridden in appropriate implementations. This does mean you need to own the interface, of course... but in some cases it would be cleaner than current extension methods. (By avoiding the ability to introduce fields, I believe you get round some implementation problems which multiple inheritance of classes would introduce.)

Second, I don't like the way extension methods are discovered. There's no way to say, "I want the extension methods from class X" without also dragging in the extension methods from other classes in the same namespace. I would like you to be able to write:

```
using static System.Linq.Enumerable;
```

to pick up *only* those extension methods.

(Incidentally, I'll be talking more about both of these points at [NDC 2010](http://www.ndc2010.no/) on Thursday. Hopefully the talk will be recorded.)

The ability to specify general algorithms which only rely on the public interface is nice. The ability to call those algorithms on the type providing the interface is nice. The current mechanism just has a few sharp corners.

Incidentally, it might be quite nice to be able to write methods *within* a type but say, "Limit me to only using the public API."

Comment: thanks for the answer :) The specialization issue _is_ the only serious snag I see with this approach; having interfaces be able to contain "default implementations" would be really nice. The `using` issue is annoying, but more an issue with `using` than with extensions, imo. Maybe a python-style approach would work? `from System.Linq use Enumerable;` is clear, and distinguishes between importing classes and namespaces.

Comment: @tzaman: Well, it's clear - but it looks like Python (or LINQ) rather than C#. I think "using static" would be more C#-y...

Comment: I've attempted a solution to the interface specialization issue, care to take a look? :)

Comment: @tzaman: Yup, that's pretty much what LINQ does, effectively. It's a bit ugly though, as you say :(

Answer (score 5):

I think that C# follows slightly different logic - just like in Java, the axiom in C# is that everything is an object and all functionality should be encapsulated in the class (as methods). C# isn't as strict - there are value types that aren't really object and there are static members, which also don't belong to any *object*.

Extension methods add one capability that wasn't possible before - you can add members to interfaces (implemented in terms of the core members of the interface). This is great and very useful, but I think it should be used only when adding member to an interface is what you need (just like the use in LINQ).

One possible problem with prefering extension methods over instance methods is that you may later realize that you actually need to use some private state in the method - then you would have to change extension method into an instance method (which breaks binary compatibility) or expose some private information...

It would be definitely usable to distinguish between members that rely on private state directly and "derived" members that are implemented in terms of public operations, but I don't think that extension methods are that great for this. Perhaps it would be possible to mark such methods with some attribute (e.g. `UsesOnlyPublic`) and write some FxCop rule to make sure that the method doesn't violate the policy...

Comment: While C# certainly isn't a strict object language, value types are still objects, they just prefer the stack to the heap...

Comment: Re: ABI - While it is a consideration, I don't see it as being that much of an issue - as long as your interface is stable, any methods that use it will be fine; if it changes enough to force an extension to become a member, you'd be breaking ABI anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Extension methods do seem to directly address the encapsulation principle that you cite.  But I do see danger in their overuse.  Without this language feature, you have basically two options for implementing your "non-member non-friend" functions that complement a given interface: static utility functions or a wrapper/proxy class.

I think the problem with the extension method approach is that it's basically a convenient syntactic construct around static utility functions.  It just provides you with method call semantics for a static utility function.

But in the absence of extension methods I think most would agree that wrapper/proxy classes are a better way to implement your "non-member non-friend" functions.  I think that this really just comes down to the organic growth of your codebase in an object-oriented way.  The class that you make today as a simple wrapper/proxy may grow into a first class component in your system tomorrow.  It's a real class, so it can have members of its own and potentially grow in scope along with your expanding use cases.

So I think extension methods have the danger of encouraging the proliferation of what are basically static utility functions at the expense of classes and objects, which are the constructs that you most want to cultivate in your codebase.

Comment: "classes and objects, which are the constructs that you most want to cultivate in your codebase" - are they, though? Functional or generic programming proponents would say otherwise; I don't think it's coincidence that (functional-inspired) LINQ is implemented via extension methods...

Comment: You're not writing in a functional language. Functional programming has its benefits but I would say you should switch languages if you don't want to make objects.  As for generic programming, being able to do generic programming in C# or C++ is really predicated on having objects.  The thing you want to avoid at all costs is creating very large objects or interfaces.  If you have many small objects with well organized interfaces, that enables template programming and much more.  To the extent that extension methods discourage creating lots of small objects, it would be a bad thing.